# maven not authorized by proxy

Tags: java, maven

I have a project maven. I have a proxy.

My proxies of settings.xml maven is

```
<proxy>
        <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy1.marm.es</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      </proxy>
    <proxy>
    <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy1.marm.es</host>
      <port>3128</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</nonProxyHosts>
     </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

I run mvn -e install

I get the error

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized by proxy
```

How do I have to configure the proxy in settings.xml?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide username password..

```
<username>proxyuser</username>
<password>somepassword</password>
```

Comment: I have configured this proxy in eclipse and it doesn't have username and password

Comment: you need to give this in the settings.xml file, which maven is using. In eclipse under preference, check maven and provide the location of your settings.xml file which will have this tags